# A problem that involves a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

We let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. How do we prove that
$$\sup \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]\right|=\sup\sum_{i=1}^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$$
where $a_i\in [-1,1]$ and the supremum is taken all divisions 
$$a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n=b$$ of $[a,b]$. The left hand side is $\le$ to the right hand side by the triangle inequality. May I ask a tip (or solution as I wish) for proving the reverse inequality?

Comment: Choose the $a_i \in \{-1,1\}$ according to the sign of $f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})$.

Comment: You mean $\{-1,1\}$, not $[-1,1]$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: put $a_i=\operatorname{sign} [f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]$.

Comment: I will try it. Thx

Comment: @juniven Yes. This way the sums from both parts of the equality will become equal.

Comment: Ahh I got it. The trick is to write $$|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=a_i[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]$$ where $a_i$ is the one you suggested. Am I right?

Comment: @juniven Yes, you are right.